# Expressing potayto-potahto, tomayto-tomahto correctly in writing

Tags: expressions, writing, spelling, phonetics

There's a saying expressing that the presented concepts are distinct without a difference. It's based on the pronunciation of *potato* and *tomato*. How would one go about **writing** that differnece in an informal way (i.e. not applying the proper phonetic notation)?

I tried the following but then I got unsure if it's intuitively correct to a NSE's ear.

> pot**ay**to-pot**ah**to, tom**ay**to-tom**ah**to

Also, now I'm unsure if it's *distinction without difference* or *difference without distinction*... Or are those two potato-tomato?

Comment: There is no "correct" way to represent differing pronunciations of words. The most consistent and informative way is to use [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), but some people have a strange aversion to this.

Comment: I don't find that aversion strange. IPA might be a great tool but learning/verifying the pronunciation using it will be rather complicated and time consuming for a layman. And it's not motivated to get into the details for a single question or two. It's not aversion. It's convenience and laziness. (Unless one considers laziness an aversion to effort, that is.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure ay and ah are reasonable ways to express /ei/ and /a:/ informally.  Splitting into syllables helps signal that these are phonetic spellings.

But note that while there is a difference in British and American pronunciation of Tomato (Brits say to-mah-to, Yanks say to-may-to)  The same is not true of "potato".  Brits and Yanks both say "Po-tay-to", despite what the song may say...

Let's give the whole thing up.

Comment: Curiosity took over. Who says *po-**tah**-to* then?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Nobody.

Comment: US Yanks say _to-may-to_ Southerners say _ta-may-ter_ or just _mater_